# Comma and Antecedant Questions from Example Text

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns, commas, subject-auxiliary-inversion

"In her lonesome cottage, by the seashore, thoughts visited her such as dared to enter no other dwelling in New England; **shadowy guests, that would have been as perilous as demons to their entertainer, could they have been seen so much as knocking at her door.**"

1. What is 'that' indicating in the sentence?
2. Is 'they' indicating 'shadowy guests'?
3. Why are the two commas used there? Are they just for pause? not for grammatical reason?
4. Why is 'the position of could' inverted ?I mean it should be "they could have been seen so much as knocking at her door." Is there any reason?

Here is the sentence in context:

> Much of the marble coldness of Hester's impression was to be attributed to the circumstance that her life had turned, in a great
>   measure, from passion and feeling to thought. Standing alone in the
>   world--alone, as to any dependence on society, and with little Pearl
>   to be guided and protected--alone, and hopeless of retrieving her
>   position, even had she not scorned to consider it desirable--she cast
>   away the fragment of a broken chain. The world's law was no law for
>   her mind. It was an age in which the human intellect, newly
>   emancipated, had taken a more active and a wider range than for many
>   centuries before. Men of the sword had overthrown nobles and kings.
>   Men bolder than these had overthrown and rearranged--not actually, but
>   within the sphere of theory, which was their most real abode--the
>   whole system of ancient prejudice, wherewith was linked much of
>   ancient principle. Hester Prynne imbibed this spirit. She assumed a
>   freedom of speculation, then common enough on the other side of the
>   Atlantic, but which our forefathers, had they known it, would have
>   held to be a deadlier crime than that stigmatised by the scarlet
>   letter. In her lonesome cottage, by the seashore, thoughts visited her
>   such as dared to enter no other dwelling in New England; **shadowy
>   guests, that would have been as perilous as demons to their
>   entertainer, could they have been seen so much as knocking at her
>   door.**

Comment: You're asking too many questions at once. Briefly, ***that*** is a [relativiser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativizer) (a conjunction introducing a relative clause), ***they*** does indeed refer back to "shadowy guests", and the commas before ***that*** and after ***entertainer*** are a "matched pair" delineating a parenthetical / optional clause. The stylistic inversion ***could they...*** represents ***IF they could...*** Consider, for example, ***Had you** limited yourself to asking about only one of these issues, I wouldn't have closevoted.***

Comment: ...note that your text is over 150 years old, and even by the literary standards of the time would have been seen as being at the very least "highly stylised". By today's standards, it's [purple prose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose) - that you definitely shouldn't aspire to emulate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I was taught that **that** cannot be used after **a comma** as a relative pronoun, but according to your comment, can the rule be ignored if a clause is made to be parenthetical or optional ?

Comment: Semantically, ***shadowy guests*** is equivalent to ***vague unwelcome thoughts***. All text after the semicolon is simply a restatement / expansion / clarification / of preceding ***thoughts***, where the semicolon could in principle be replaced by a dash or period. And if that text had been shorter (and thus easier for the reader to parse), the comma might not have been needed. Consider *In her cottage, thoughts visited her. Thoughts that she did not welcome.* A comma *definitely* doesn't work there, but you could optionally include one if you qualified them as ***Unpleasant** thoughts*.

Comment: ...thus we see that simply including an adjective in the preceding noun phrase / NP referenced by ***that*** significantly affects whether or not you can include a comma / pause in speech before it. Which probably implies that the "rule" you've been taught is limited in scope.

Comment: @EvaristeGalois  be aware that "The Scarlet Letter" was written in 1850 when florid and circumlocutory prose was not only accepted, but expected (and is a common headache for students forced to study the novel in high school English literature classes).  It would sound strange to write like this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

**That** is introducing a relative clause, therefore it's a relativiser. As a matter of fact, ME doesn't necessitate a comma put before it, however, earlier it was the grammatically correct sentence construction. **That** could be replaced with **which** (which does need a comma if it is a non-restrictive clause).

2)

**They** relates to **shadowy guests** that relates to **thoughts**.

3)

The first comma is explained under 1), the third is put there because that part of the sentence is an inversion of the second conditional. If there were an **if**, no comma could be used.

4)

...but the writer used inversion, that is, a comma has to be put there. Inversion heightens the feeling or sensation of the work's literary value and it's no surprise if inversion comes up in a literary text. Here are some additional sentences to see how inversion works:

> **Should** you have any problem, please don't hesitate to contact me. (1st conditional)
>
> **Were** you my son, I'd show you what good manners are. (2nd condition)
>
> **Had** you read the book, you would know what it is about. (3rd condition)